# Pandas: Columna datetime genera fechas adicionales erroneas al ordenar o aplicar resample()

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

estoy intentando ordenar una columna datetimes que tiene rango entre 2016-01-01 y 2019-02-14. La columna la extraigo desde un dataframe que descargue de aquí ([Datos](https://datos.cdmx.gob.mx/explore/dataset/carpetas-de-investigacion-pgj-cdmx/table/)). Uno de los problemas que encontré es que las fechas no tienen un formato uniforme entonces cargue el CSV como:

```
DATA=pd.read_csv('carpetas-de-investigacion-pgj- 
cdmx.csv',sep=';',parse_dates=['Fecha inicio'])
```

Posteriormente separo la columna "Fecha inicio" y quito el tiempo para quedarme solo con las fechas:

```
tm=DATA[['Fecha inicio']]
tm['Fecha inicio']=tm['Fecha inicio'].dt.date
tm['Fecha inicio']=pd.to_datetime(tm['Fecha inicio'])
```

si hago solo eso obtengo el rango de fechas que va desde "2016-05-01 : 2019-02-14" pero el rango inicia en "2016-01-01" así que ordeno los datos usando

```
tm.sort_values('Fecha inicio')
```

pero al hacer eso obtengo "2016-01-01 : 2019-12-02" donde efectivamente empieza en "2016-01-01" pero no finaliza en 2019-12-02 sino en "2019-02-14". También me di cuenta que esto me genera problemas con al aplicar resample porque al hacerlo es como si tuviera datos hasta el "2019-12-02(02/Dic/2019)" lo cual no es posible porque los datos llegan solo hasta el 14 de Febrero de 2019. Muestro a continuación el código cuando hago un re-muestreo y su plot respectivo:

```
df7=DATA.groupby(['Fecha inicio']) 
['Delito'].size().reset_index(name='No delitos').sort_values(by='Fecha 
inicio',ascending=True)

df7.set_index('Fecha inicio',inplace=True)

df7.resample('M').agg({'No delitos':sum}).replace(np.nan,0).plot()
```

esta es la salida del código anterior

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me di cuenta que el formato de las fechas del dataframe original no son homogeneas pues a partir de 2019 el formato camabia. Ya intente cambiar los formatos manualmente pero obtengo los mismos resultados. No sé cómo resolverlo. Espero haya sido claro con mi problema y me puedan dar algunas sugerencias de qué podría ser. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas puede inferir el formato de fecha, incluso cuando los datos no son *homogéneos* como es este caso.

Prueba con las siguiente opciones que tiene [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
DATA = pd.read_csv('carpetas-de-investigacion-pgj-cdmx.csv',
                   sep=';',
                   parse_dates=['Fecha inicio'],
                   infer_datetime_format=True,
                   dayfirst=True)
```

Con `infer_datetime_format=True`, *pandas* intentará deducir el formato de la fecha.

Con `dayfirst=True`, tomará el formato `DD/MM/AAAA` para la fecha.

Comment: Perfecto, funcionó de maravilla. Llevaba dos días probando y no salía pero nunca pensé en usar tu sugerencia. Ya también al hacer re-muestro funciona perfecto. Muchas gracias.